# Git checkout branchname creates files which are not in git log

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```sh
 ✗ git rm -f styleguide/public/patterns/05-templates-Right-Sidebar/index.html 
rm 'styleguide/public/patterns/05-templates-Right-Sidebar/index.html'
 ✗ git checkout WEB-6862-update
Updating files: 100% (3876/3876), done.
Switched to branch 'WEB-6862-update'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/WEB-6862-update'.
 ✗ ls styleguide/public/patterns/05-templates-Right-Sidebar/index.html
styleguide/public/patterns/05-templates-Right-Sidebar/index.html
 ✗ git log styleguide/public/patterns/05-templates-Right-Sidebar/index.html
 ✗
```

How can that happen and how can I fix it? There's nothing in git hooks.

Comment: Call `git rm -f ...` instead. But this is Git 101 basically. You have to understand difference between index and local copy. And a staged change as well (I forgot how it's correctly called in Git terms). You may check with `git status --ignored` what is going on.

Comment: This breaks `git rebase` completely, not sure what index has to do with this and I understand the difference between the two or so I thought.

Comment: I am completely confused now. How `git rebase` appeared on the table?

Comment: I tried git rm -f, I edited the question with it, doesn't change  a thing.

Comment: Run `git status --ignored` before each command.

Comment: And quite likely the `git reset --hard HEAD~0` will fix it, but it's quite dangerous, it will remove any changes which you made but not yet committed.

Comment: The reason for this is case (in)sensitivity. I am on WSL.  I will see how to fix it and post an answer.